# Progress OpenEdge 11.7 Driver to SSMS 18.6 Connection

Tags: sql, odbc, ssms, openedge, progress-db

I'm pretty new to SQL and finally got my DBA to hook me up with SSMS (I've been using Microsoft query for months and loathing it). Now that I have it installed I can't seem to get it to talk to my server which is built on Progress. I have the ODBC driver set up in my System DSN under the ODBC Data Source Administrator. Any ideas on how to get this into SSMS-I've tried everything I can think of to add it but am clearly missing something? Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a linked server on an existing SQL server database that will query progress through ODBC. To make your queries  faster, you can use `openquery` which is going to run joins directly on server side.

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000044836